Is it possible to chain multi readers in spring batch?
What I want is to read the value from the database in the first reader, The goal is to pass the value as a parameter to the second leader.
ex) 100 row table A firstPagingReader 0 ~ 10 row -> second Reader -> processor -> writer firstPagingReader 11 ~ 20 row -> second Reader -> processor -> writer
I want to operate sequentially like this.
In this case, is there no choice but to handle it with a tasklet?
The reason why this structure is necessary is to improve query performance by taking the values ​​of conditions required for the second read from the first read.
I tried a lot of searches, but couldn't find a suitable answer.

No, there is no such reader in Spring Batch. You need to create a custom reader that combines the two.

You can developed a code for CustomFlatFileItemReader and cache the data or set it into JobParameters to be able to send it to the next step.
